# What is the exitContext used for on a WaitHandle.WaitOne method

Tags: c#, multithreading

Example

```
System.Threading.AutoResetEvent e = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
bool b = e.WaitOne(1000, false);
```

I've done a lot of multi threaded development in my time and have always wondered what the use of the that method was for. The second boolean parameter on the WaitOne is called exitContext. MS Help states
        "true to exit the synchronization domain for the context before the wait (if in a synchronized context), and reacquire it afterward; otherwise, false."

Anyone any idea what this means? Is it something I should be worried about?

Kind Regards
Noel

Comment: Damned fine question. I've always wondered the same thing, yet never needed to use it... AFAIK !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't claim credit (hence wiki) but there is a good answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ea5aea17-555c-4549-8d32-bbab14b35a77).

From the link, answer to the question, by [Sasha Goldshtein](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/sasha%20goldshtein/?ws=usercard-mini)

> The CLR has support for a notion called contexts.  A context is a
> logical grouping of objects.  When a method call is made on an object
> that is inside your context, nothing in particular happens except for
> the method itself.  When a method call is made on an object that is
> outside your context, then "something" might happen before the method
> itself is executed.  All .NET classes derived from `ContextBoundObject`
> will be associated with a context at runtime.
>
> An example of that "something" that can happen before the method is
> called would be enforcing synchronization.  An object that derives
> from `ContextBoundObject` and specifies the `[Synchronization]` attribute
> will get automatic synchronization services from the runtime.  This
> means that only one thread will ever be able to execute within the
> object's context.
>
> The `exitContext` parameter of the `WaitOne` method specifies whether to
> leave the synchronization context before issuing the wait.  This
> enables reentrancy.  Here's a scenario where this is necessary:
>
> Code Snippet
>
> ```
> [Synchronization]
> public class MyCounter : ContextBoundObject {
>  
>   private int _expectedCounterVal;
>   private int _currentCounterVal; 
>   private ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
>
>   public void WaitUntilCounterIs(int counterVal) {  
>     _expectedCounterVal = counterVal;
>     _event.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), true);
>   }
>
>   public void IncrementCounter() {
>     if (++_currentCounterVal >= _expectedCounterVal) {    
>       _event.Set();
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, if the `WaitUntilCounterIs` method is issued without the
> `exitContext=true` parameter of the `WaitOne` method, then no other thread
> will be able to ever call the `IncrementCounter` method on the object,
> resulting in a deadlock.  However, once `exitContext=true` is specified,
> other threads can enter the `IncrementCounter` method and signal the
> event at some point, even though the `WaitUntilCounterIs` method has not
> yet returned.

Comment: Thanks for the Link Marc, explains it perfectly.

Comment: In case the link becomes unavailable someday, the bottom line is that you only need to worry about `exitContext` if you are using a class deriving from `ContextBoundObject` and having a [Synchronization] attribute.